# Overriding setOnCheckedChangeListener in Android

Tags: android, overriding

I have a set of switch components, around 30. I want to override the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` so that I can avoid unnecessary code that does nearly the same thing.

I know, it is possible for **onClick** function, so using multiple buttons and changing the logic in the overridden function is way better.

What I have so far is:

```
final Switch question1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.question1);
    question1.setText(R.string.no);
    question1.setChecked(false);
    question1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                question1.setText(R.string.yes);
            } else {
                question1.setText(R.string.no);
            }

            UpdateScores();
        }
    });

    final Switch question2 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.question2);
    question2.setText(R.string.no);
    question2.setChecked(false);
    question2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                question2.setText(R.string.yes);
            } else {
                question2.setText(R.string.no);
            }

            UpdateScores();
        }
    });
```

As can be seen much of the code is replicated and I don't want that. Is there any way to achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create **one** listener for all your switchers.

```
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    buttonView.setText(R.string.yes);
                } else {
                    buttonView.setText(R.string.no);
                }

                UpdateScores();
            }
```

And then add this listener to your Switchers:

```
question1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
question2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
....
question30.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
```

Comment: This seems great! I'll try it right away, thank you!

Comment: Can I also change the logic based on the id of the component?

Comment: Sure you can... use `buttonView.getId();`.

Comment: Thank you! You saved the day!

Answer (score 0):

```
OnCheckedChangeListner onchange = new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
     @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                 boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            buttonView.setText(R.string.yes);
        } else {
            buttonView.setText(R.string.no);
        }

        UpdateScores();
    }
}

 question2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onchange);
```

you want it?